# Use awk to analyze csv file - combined with shell 'date' command in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a .csv file which has dates and the answer about enjoyable or not:

```
2019-04-1,enjoyable
2019-04-2,unenjoyable
2019-04-3,unenjoyable
2019-04-4,enjoyable
2019-04-5,unenjoyable
2019-04-6,unenjoyable
2019-04-7,enjoyable
2019-04-8,unenjoyable
2019-04-9,unenjoyable
2019-04-10,enjoyable
2019-04-11,enjoyable
2019-04-12,enjoyable
2019-04-13,unenjoyable
2019-04-14,enjoyable
2019-04-15,unenjoyable
2019-04-16,unenjoyable
2019-04-17,unenjoyable
2019-04-18,enjoyable
2019-04-19,unenjoyable
2019-04-20,unenjoyable
2019-04-21,unenjoyable
2019-04-22,unenjoyable
2019-04-23,unenjoyable
2019-04-24,unenjoyable
2019-04-25,unenjoyable
2019-04-26,unenjoyable
```

What I want to do is to print the day of the week in the third column seperate by ',' like this:

```
2019-04-1,enjoyable,2
2019-04-2,unenjoyable,3
```

I tried:

```
dates=$(awk '{FS=","}{print $1,$2}' weather_stat.csv')

weeks=$(
for vars in $dates[first_row]
do
echo $(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' $vars "+%w")
done
)

merge($dates,$weeks)
```

The first part of the code works without any problem, but in the second part, I am confused about how to get the data in the first row (so I use dates[first_row] to mean the first row in dates variable) from the variable "dates" so we can apply 'date' method on it

And for the third part, I want to merge these two tables together. I found the 'join' function but it seem to work on two files instead of two variables(I don't want to have any new files during the process)

Could anyone tells me how to get the rows in a variable instead of a file in shell and the way to merge two table-like variables?

Comment: Typically, Monday is day number 1. With `%w`, Sunday is day 0; with `%u`, Sunday is day 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're learning shell scripting, here's some code to study:

1. to read your csv file, and get the weekday number for each date in the file:

   ```
   while IFS=, read -r date rest; do echo "$date,$(date -d "$date" +%w)"; done < file.csv
   ```
2. to join the output of that command with your file:

   ```
   weekdays=$(while IFS=, read -r date rest; do echo "$date,$(date -d "$date" +%w)"; done < file.csv)
   join -t, file.csv <(echo "$weekdays")
   ```

   or, without needing to store the result in an intermediate variable

   ```
   join -t, file.csv <(
       while IFS=, read -r date rest; do echo "$date,$(date -d "$date" +%w)"; done < file.csv
   )
   ```

   The newlines within the `<()` are not necessary, but useful for maintainable code.

However, you can see that this is less efficient because you have to process the file twice. With awk you only have to read through the file once.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk' BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     { split($1,a,"-")
       t=sprintf("%0.4d %0.2d %0.2d 00 00 00",a[1],a[2],a[3]);
       print $0,strftime("%w",mktime(t))
     }' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks,but is there anyway to apply shell methods in variables instead of files? like `join $var1 $var2`

Comment: @YilingLiu I'm not following your question. You have a CSV file, and you want this output. Why do you want to use shell variables? Also the command `join` works with files so `$var1` and `$var2` must be files,

Comment: Also, the time format comes first: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Comment: I am a new shell learner and I used to use python before. I thought that using the variable to store outcomes of the previous command is much easier to understand for me

Comment: Not so: `awk 'BEGIN {print mktime("2019 04 26 01 02 03"); print mktime("2019 4 26 1 2 3")}'`

Comment: @YilingLiu you REALLY should be using GNU awk for this rather than a shell loop. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Answer (score 1):

With only your Bourne shell, so less efficient than awk if you have a lot of lines in your CSV file:

```
while IFS=, read date enjoy; do
    date -d "$date" +"$date,$enjoy,%w"
done < your.csv
```

Comment: I would avoid putting the variables into the date format: what if some `%X` formatters end up in the csv file? More robust to use echo or printf`

Comment: I assume the format of the CSV lines is as given in the question: ```YYYY-M[M]-D[D],[un]enjoyable```. If you start to assume otherwise, for example that dates may contain strange characters, then none of the answers will be valid.